# Some questions about functions of Ordinal Numbers

Tags: set-theory

Does there exist a strictly increasing and continuous function of ordinal numbers whose
smallest critical number (i.e. fixed point) is the smallest non-constructive ordinal
number (in the sense of Church and Kleene)? If so, does there exist such a function all
of whose critical numbers (i.e. fixed points) are non-constructive and admissible ordinal numbers?

Comment: Doesn't $f(\alpha)=$ first admissible past $\omega+\alpha$ work?

Comment: Andres, I take strictly increasing to mean: $\alpha\lt\beta\implies f(\alpha)<f(\beta)$, but your function is constant on intervals.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Ah, strictly, yes. Thanks. So, let's take $f(\alpha)=\alpha$-th admissible ordinal past $\omega$.

Comment: But that will jump past $\omega_1^{CK}$, which I thought was to be the fixed point.

Comment: It’s an easy exercise to show that every ordinal of the form $\omega^\alpha$ with countable cofinality is the least fixed point of some strictly increasing continuous function. Then extend it as Andres says. This does not really have anything to do with admissibility.

Comment: Andres, the function in your second comment is not continuous, since the admissible ordinals do not form a club. (But you fix this issue in your answer.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, I got annoyed at my imprecision, so I decided to post an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any admissible ordinal is the limit of indecomposable ordinals. Pick an $\omega$-sequence of these ordinals, $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\dots$ with limit $\omega_1^{CK}$, so the order type of $[\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1}]$ is $\alpha_{i+1}$. Now define $f$ on $[0,\alpha_0]$ by $f(\beta)=\alpha_0+1+\beta$, on $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$ by $f(\beta)=\alpha_1+\beta$, on $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2]$ by $f(\beta)=\alpha_2+\beta$, etc. Then define for $\beta\ge\omega_1^{CK}$, $f(\beta)=\beta$. This $f$ is normal, and has $\omega_1^{CK}$ as its first fixed point. Note that the fact that $\omega_1^{CK}$ is admissible is irrelevant here; in fact, all that matters here is that it has countable cofinality, and is indecomposable.

If instead we want $f(\alpha)$ to be admissible for each $\alpha$, pick a club through the admissible ordinals, and let $f$ be its increasing enumeration. Suppose for instance that $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, and note that then there is a club of $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $V_\alpha\prec V_\kappa$, but each such $\alpha$ is of course admissible. We can easily relax the assumptions, to turn this into an argument that there is indeed, provably in $\mathsf{ZF}$, a (proper class) club of admissible ordinals. Note, on the other hand, that a limit of admissible ordinals need not be admissible, so some care is needed.

Comment: You don’t need the individual $\alpha_i$ to be indecomposable. Thus defined $f$ is always strictly increasing and continuous, so you only need to ensure that it takes values below the limit, i.e., that the limit is indecomposable.

Comment: Yes, all I need is that the intervals $(\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1})$ have length larger than $\alpha_i$.

Comment: Not even that. The last value assigned in the $i$th interval is $\alpha_i+\alpha_i$, and the first value assigned in the next one is $\alpha_{i+1}+\alpha_i+1\ge\alpha_i+\alpha_i+1>\alpha_i+\alpha_i$. Or to put it simply, $f(\beta)$ is a sum of two numbers, the first of which is nondecreasing, and the second is strictly increasing, hence the result is strictly increasing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. All that matters is that $\omega_1^{CK}$ itself is (countable and) indecomposable.

Comment: Thanks alot for all this information. I asked these questions in order to get a clearer intuitive picture of

Comment: Thanks alot for all this information. I asked these questions in order to obtain a clearer intuitive picture of the set of admissible ordinal numbers, which is often defined in rather complicated ways.